# EXCEL 2013 VBA Querying two files on separate databases on different servers at same time

Tags: excel, vba, ado

I only have moderate experience when it comes to EXCEL VBA and ADO.  I have two files a task file and a calendar file each of which is on a different database and a different server. I need to determine the number of actual work days associated to the task. So I need to take the timestamp date from the task file, check it against the calendar file to determine how many days in the task are actual working days. I figured out how to open two separate database connections in my VBA Script, but what I cannot figure out is how to combine the two files so I can get a working days count.

Something like this

```
Select Taskid, count(*) 
From TaskFile, Calendar
Where TaskDate >= CalendarDate
And   TaskDate <= CalendarDate
And   CalendarWorkDay = 1
Group by  Taskid
```

I thought about preloading a worksheet with the calendar data but don't see how the query will work.

Any suggestions or code snippets would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might consider pulling back both recordsets and sticking them on their own worksheets, then using ADODB to join those two sets of data and stick them in a third sheet. I just wrote a quickie VBA to query an excel workbook for another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266244/excel-vba-to-find-duplicate-rows-and-sum-rows/26266824#26266824 It wouldn't take much to modify.

Comment: Also, if you aren't pulling many records in the first query, then maybe just loop through the results and fire off a SELECT on the second connection for each record. If it's many records though.. then that's probably not a great solution.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. On the idea of merging the two sheets into a third, not sure I would be able to do a count for value in a range that way.  On the second suggestion of looping through the data, that might just work. Can you tell me what to focus on when looking it up or a shove in the direction of how to to do it as I must admit I have no idea how to do that.  Thanks again for your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick and dirty subroutine that will do something like what I suggested in the second comment above. It probably won't work exactly as you need it to right out of the box, but the overall idea is sound. Just realize that every record returned in the first query will generate a new query to the second file/database, so it could get pretty hairy if there are a lot of records.

```
Sub twoRecordsets()
    Dim objConn As ADODB.Connection, objConn2 As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strConn As String, strconn2 As String

    'open first connection
    Set objConn = New ADODB.Connection
    strConn = "<your 1st connection string>"
    objConn.Open strConn

    'open second connection
    Set objConn2 = New ADODB.Connection
    strconn2 = "<your 2nd connection string>"
    objConn2.Open strconn2

    'first query:
    strSQL = "Select Taskid, TaskDate From TaskFile GROUP BY TaskID"

    'open first recordset using first query
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open strSQL, objConn

    'Die if there are no records returned
    If rs.EOF And rs.BOF Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Loop through recordset
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do Until rs.EOF

        'build a sql statement to do the second bit. might have to monkey with quote marks and date formats depending on DB
        strSQL = "SELECT count(*) as recordcount FROM calendar where '" & rs.Fields("TaskDate").Value & "' >= CalendarDate And '" & rs.Fields("TaskDate").Value & "' <= CalendarDate And CalendarWorkDay = 1"

        'open recordset
        Set rs2 = New ADODB.Recordset
        rs2.Open strSQL, objConn2

        'Get your answer from the return
        heresYourAnswer = rs2.Fields("recordcount").Value

        'Iterate to next record in rs
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: Took some time to really study what you provided and I get it.  I was able to fit the code to what I am doing.  Last question is related to the results in the RS 2. The point of the calendar is to determine actual work hours which I want to include next to the calendar hours in RS 1. Can I write the results from RS 2 into RS 1  or do I somehow merge RS 1 & RS 2 together into a RS 3?  I am planning on doing research on EXCEL and Records Sets to see if I can sort out the answer on my own also. You been very sporting with your time, code and support thanks again.